# How to intergrate elFinder in tinymce of version 5?

Tags: tinymce, elfinder, tinymce-5

We got a new version of TinyMCE. And this is the 5th version. And I want to integrate elFinder 2 in that. But I don't know how. Would you help?

I've researched documentation of version 5 of TinyMCE and didn't find any data which helps me. But I got this code for the integration of elFinder which help in the half of this target.

Here is my find code for open elFinder:

```
file_picker_callback: {
   function (callback, value, meta) {

        tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.openUrl({
                title: "elFinder",
                url: "/admin/js/elfinder/elfinder.html",
        });
   }
}
```

I expect that the dbclick event will put data of image which get this event in the window of the inserting image in the editor.

Comment: have you tried the way that its integrated in earlier versions? like 4.x? https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-4.x

Comment: also, what do you mean by "which help in the half of this target"

Comment: I have tried to do that. But that code not working anymore in version 5 of TinyMCE.
And I mean that we need to do some steps to achieve the goal in that target. And the target is to get a link of an image or some media content and put it in some area where we initialized TinyMCE the image link.

And this is what we need exactly:
1) Open TinyMCE window with elFinder
2) Select some file
3) Put the link and other data of the file in appropriate poles.
4) Click the button "Insert" and see how the image or another kind of content will appear in TinyMCE initialized pole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I'm posting the solution which I found.

You need to open the link [official guide of elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-4.x)

And find the next link for the plugin "tinymceElfinder"
 on the image [link to the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbg9y.png)

But if you will not find this link I publish the link.
Here you are the magic link [click to find the magic plugin for fans of TinyMCE 5](https://github.com/nao-pon/tinymceElfinder)

Comment: I thiln you sould postthe final code that you used and not just the links, what if they get down? :)

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE APIs for UI elements have changed in TinyMCE 5 so code for TinyMCE 4 won't work in TinyMCE 5.

I would ask the folks that created elFinder if they have working code for TinyMCE 5.  TinyMCE 5 was released in February so it is relatively new and elFinder may not have updated their examples just yet.

Comment: I think this should be a comment

Comment: Michael, I found the solution!

Comment: I found the magic link of the solution on this page https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-4.x on upper of the page.

And here the solution link of the solution itself
https://github.com/nao-pon/tinymceElfinder And it's really working!

Comment: @AlexanderBulatov So post an answer for the next ones :)